# Как получить результат асинхронной функции с помощью коллбека?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо внести правки в функцию asyncOperation и реализовать использование функций обратного вызова для того чтобы код, вызвавший asyncOperation, мог получить результат работы асинхронной операции. Вызовите асинхронную операцию и используя функцию обратного вызова обработайте результат, отобразив его через alert.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function() {
    asyncOperation();
    console.log(result);
})

function asyncOperation() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        let result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5001);
    }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4un9sawp/

Comment: Это не асинхронная функция, а обыкновенная. (Асинхронные функции записываются так: `async function и т.д.`)

Comment: Объект ```Promise``` используется для отложенных и асинхронных вычислений

Comment: Нужно именно через коллбек

Comment: обернуть функцию в промис.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Раньше с помощью таймеров и делали асинхронный код

Comment: @Mr.Man "Как получить результат **асинхронной функции** с помощью коллбека?"

Comment: @ΝNL993 легко. Завернуть в функцию с колбеком. Но вообще вы очень узко трактуете понятие «асинхронная функция».